# Newbie question: Problem with results, sql, join, where, "<" operator

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, where-clause

TASK:

> Show the last names of employees, employees salary, and their managers
>   last names and salary. We are only interested in those employees who
>   were hired before their managers and have salary below the average
>   of their departments.

CODE:

```
select e.last_name, e.salary, e.hire_date, e.department_id,
       m.last_name, m.salary, m.hire_date 
from employees e  
join employees m  on (e.manager_id=m.employee_id) 
 where e.salary <(select avg(e.salary) 
                  from employees e  
                  where e.department_id=e.department_id) 
and e.hire_date < m.hire_date
```

PROBLEM:

I have a problem with results. Among them I got

- one employee with
  salary equal to department average (Rajs)
- one employee without department_id (Grant)
- one employee which works in a single person department (Whalen).

However, when I changed `<` operator between `e.salary < (select avg(e.salary)...` to opposite `>` (assuming that this time we are interested in those who have salary above department average), the results are correct.

I cannot understand why it works in this way? I've tried to workaround this problem by adding this line

```
 and e.salary<>(select avg(e.salary) 
               from employees e 
               where e.department_id=e.department_id)`
```

but it doesn't work. Can anybody help me understand what is going on or just show direction?

Here is my table:
[image]

Comment: A good question from a new user, where you show the issue, the code, some data. For the next time, if you could [avoid screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) it would be perfect. +1 for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a subtle problem. In your subquery you have aliased `employees e` which is same as the alias you used in the main query. This means the filter in the subquery `e.department_id=e.department_id` does not actually do what you think it does:  Due to namespace scoping it actually collapses to `1=1`. So you don't get the results you're expecting as the subquery is not correlated.

The solution is simple: use a different alias in the subquery, like this:

```
select e.last_name, e.salary, e.hire_date, e.department_id,
       m.last_name, m.salary, m.hire_date 
from employees e  
join employees m  on (e.manager_id=m.employee_id) 
 where e.salary <(select avg(e2.salary) 
                  from employees e2  
                  where e.department_id=e2.department_id) 
and e.hire_date < m.hire_date
;
```

Comment: Yes, that solves the problem. Thank You very much for help and editing.

Comment: @APC . . . It doesn't quite collapse to `1=1`.  It is equivalent to `e.department_id is not null`.  Doesn't make a different in this case, but it might in others.